# Command similar to 'yes' but that outputs newlines?

Tags: utilities

Is there a Linux command similar to `yes` but one that outputs newlines? Something like

> $ yes <kbd>enter</kbd>

That outputs

```
\n\n\n\n\n\n
```

Similar too how `yes 'foo'` outputs

```
foo
foo
foo
```

Comment: Sorry for some reason '<enter>' disappeared.  The question is "Is there a linux command similar to 'yes' but one that outputs '<enter>'?

Comment: maybe..., `yes enter`?

Comment: By `<enter>` do you mean the literal string `<enter>` or the carriage return?

Comment: You can give `yes` an empty string argument i.e. `yes ''` - if you just want repeated newlines

Answer (score 15):

Similar to what was mentioned in the comments, this will do it:

```
yes '<enter>'
```

Will output the literal string `<enter>`, or you can use `''` for newlines.

```
yes ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @EvanCarroll.  I considered adding that as well but wasn't convinced that was what the OP wanted.

Comment: just tried in osx `~$ yes ''| cp -i a.a b.b` and it said
`overwrite b.b? (y/n [n]) not overwritten`

Answer (score 4):

Well, if `yes ''` wasn't good enough (and it is) but you just wanted to show off by being more esoteric you could always do

```
tr \\000 \\n < /dev/zero
```

Comment: In both senses, the answer to the question asked is `yes`.  (-: